# I played around with netsh interface ip config and ended up resetting everything in there

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I was trying to change my DNS and since I forgot which one was my last one i just reset it all and now it seems there are some configurations missing. Does this look fine?:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::45c2:3e:d161:931d%35
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.147.29
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Unknown adapter Conexión de área local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Conexión de área local* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Conexión de área local* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Conexión de área local* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1069:87c0:9abc:a5ca%29
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.165.202
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::89e0:3915:13bc:8fac%18
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.143.172
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::912c:8648:88bb:ab91%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.8
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Did you do `ipconfig /all`? `ipconfig` by default doesn't show DNS server settings (although it does show DNS _suffixes_, contrary to the help text).

Answer (score 0):

By doing the reset, you assigned an Automatic Private IP Address ([APIPA](https://study-ccna.com/apipa-automatic-private-ip-addressing/)), which is basically giving  a default IP (between 169.254.0.1-169.254.255.254) to each network interface card that does not have a DHCP server in their broadcast domain. However, in your case, your Wi-Fi interface seems to be fine since it got a private address probably received from the DHCP server in your router. You can ping 8.8.8.8 to ensure network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless looks OK, everything else is incorrect. 169.254 is the "no DHCP" address assigned.

You have VMware network connections.

Run the VMware Network Editor, use the Admin setting, and reset the network connections. If you are using VMware Player and may not have the Editor, uninstall VMware Player temporarily.

Restart (you will have to after using the network editor) and then run TCP / IP Reset

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

(2) ipconfig /flushdns

(3) restart the computer

After the final restart, Ethernet should be back correct and then check VMware. If using VMware Player, you can reinstall it at this point.